# Can I manpulate Little Snitch access control lists via CLI on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line, python, little-snitch

I am running Little Snitch on Mac OS X, which lets me control how individual processes access the network.

Currently, every time a new application tries to go online, I have to confirm or deny its access rights. I would like to generally maintain this behavior.

The problem I have is this: I also use the Python `virtualenv` module to create isolated environments for web development with Django and Tornado. I have lots of scripts (executed through `virtualenvwrapper`) to automate all the boilerplate configuration and setup -- but a newly created `virtualenv` contains its own copy of the Python interpreter executable, which is a completely new application as far as Little Snitch is concerned.

As a result, for every new `virtualenv` created, a Little Snitch dialog pops up during the automated setup asking about the permissions for the "new" Python executable, and I have to set the permissions and click "Accept".

Is there a way to set these Little Snitch permissions on the command line? I'd like to be able to run my environment setup scripts without babysitting the GUI throughout the whole (otherwise automated) affair.

Comment: Hello from the future! Little Snitch 5 added a command-line interface which doesn't appear to do what you're asking for (yet), but it's “still under active development,” so keep an eye on [this space](https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch5/adv-commandline).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of of any CLI utility to solve your problem, but Little Snitch does allow for automatic approval of new requests within a specified time period.  This may not be the best option for you, but it will get your app out to the Internet provided it's using an appropriate timeout.